# Tell visual studios to skip over?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

While debugging i press F11 often to step into a function. For this project i use properties everwhere which is simply a RAII wrapper that checks if i have set the variable and gives me an assert if i have not. Its been useful.

However now debugging is annoying since F11 will step into the property. Can i skip it somehow? by writing attributes, keywords or anything?

I am using VS11beta

Comment: Is this managed or unmanaged code?

Comment: @CodyGray: oops, i forgot to tag it. Its using unmanaged C++

Comment: @EranZimmerman: Nope, F10 is over. I want to go IN the function

Comment: Sorry, my bad. As I see it, either put a breakpoint just inside the function (or breakpoint for a function by name) and use F5, or use step-into and step-out (I believe shift+F11, IIRC) to go over the properties and reach the function.

Comment: Well yeah thats what i am mostly doing. I have to do (F11,shift+F11)*param count which is irritating. I dont know which function i'll be going so i cant place a breakpoint unless i am debugging that location more than once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easy to set up when you're dealing with managed code. You can manually mark the function with the [`DebuggerHiddenAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute.aspx) class, and even turn on built-in debugger settings like "Step over properties and operators".

Unfortunately, automatically stepping over a particular function is not supported by Visual Studio for native C++ code. (At least, it wasn't supported up until VS 2010—I haven't had enough time to play with VS 11 to see if this is something they gave us to make up for the fact that they stole all our colors.)

There *is* a workaround, though, documented a long while ago on Andy Pennell's blog:
[How to Not Step Into Functions using the Visual C++ Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx)

Essentially, you edit the following registry key (for VS 2010):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\NativeDE\StepOver
```

or for 64-bit applications:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\NativeDE\StepOver
```

to specify a regular expression that will be matched against functions by the debugger.

For example, if you don't want the debugger to step into overloaded operators, you can use the following expression:

```
\scope:operator\oper:=NoStepInto
```

As the disclaimer in the blog post says:

> This is not a documented feature. Well obviously you are reading this “documentation” right here, but what I mean is that is not guaranteed to work as it was never officially tested, not is it supported by Microsoft. Its existence in future versions or update to current versions is not guaranteed.

Comment: Apparently the syntax for the registry key has changed in VS2010. Now you need to use something like `boost\:\:shared_ptr.*` to avoid stepping into `boost::shared_ptr.*` (taken from [here](http://kennyknecht.blogspot.com/2010/05/visual-studio-2010-nostepinto.html))